# odbc_connect to progress database

Tags: php, openedge

I could use some help determining what is the best way for me as the developer to see what is causing an error as I am trying to connect to a progress openedge database.
All I am seeing is that the connection is failing based on the `die` message.

In short I am simply looking for more verbose error logging/messaging from the odbc_connect function.

I have a production computer that this is running on just fine, so I would like to know on my new development machine what is missing.

```
$my_port = "3500";
$my_username = "my_username";
$my_password = "my_password";
$my_database = "my_db";
//0  (READ UNCOMMITTED)
//1  (READ COMMITTED)
//2  (REPEATABLE READ)
//3  (SERIALIZABLE)
$my_dil = 0;
$my_connection = odbc_connect(
"Driver={Progress OpenEdge 11.7 Driver};
                                      HOST=$progress_host;
                                      PORT=$my_port;
                                      DB=$my_database;
                                      UID=$my_username;
                                      PWD=$my_password;
                                      DIL=$my_dil", "", ""
) or die ("ERROR: Could not connect to Progress OpenEdge Database.");
```

Comment: assume you tried [function.odbc-errormsg.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php) ?

Comment: I did, however it didn't yield any fruit. It was just a blank string.

Comment: Is the database running it's sql-broker? That's not always the case for Progress OpenEdge databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out how to connect. I know that doesn't give us error handling, but it does allow us to actually connect.

I added the following to php.ini and validated they were in the ext folder; then restarted iis.

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

I needed to install the drivers on my development box. I did this by moving the progressx86 folder from my working server.

I then ran the following file.

`C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\install\odbc\sql-odbc-setup.exe`

Note:

There might be other steps that I tried before this one that affected the outcome, but before I did my answer above it didn't work, and after I did my answer above it worked.